# In a View why can't you initialise @State of type Date in the same manner as String?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Give that both Date and String are value types, why does the Date version of the following code not compile?

```swift
struct StringTest: View {
    
    @State private var value: String
    
    init(initialValue: String) {
        self.value = initialValue  /// <- All good
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(value.description)
    }
}

struct DateTest: View {
    
    @State private var value: Date
    
    init(initialValue: Date) {
        self.value = initialValue /// <- Variable 'self.value' used before being initialized
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(value.description)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if the first syntax worked it's wrong. The recommended way to initialize a `@State` property is

```
init(initialValue: String) {
    _value = State(wrappedValue: initialValue)
}
```

Comment: Yes - but still strange though how the error message only appears with Date.